# Can we have Worksheet_Change & Worksheet_SelectionChange in the same worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

Can we have Worksheet_Change & Worksheet_SelectionChange in the same worksheet.
If Yes what is the precedence?

Thank you

Jean

Comment: Well, one would fire when the selection changed and the other when the value of a cell changed through direct user interaction.  You can isolate them by using the `Application.EnableEvents = False` function.  Make sure you turn it back to true before exiting the sub.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Debug.Print Target.Row
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal myTarget As Range)

Debug.Print myTarget.Address
End Sub
```

The selection change happens first, since you change the selection before changing a cell.

Comment: If i change a cells value and hit enter or click somewhere else, _Change fires before _SelectionChange. I don't know why and I don't know on what that depends.

Answer (score 1):

You could test this super easy by sticking the following in your worksheet's VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "Change"
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  MsgBox "selection change"
End Sub
```

You'll find that the events generally don't fire at the same time unless you enter new text in a cell and hit enter to move to a new cell. In that case, the "Change" event will fire first, then the "Selection Change" will fire.